# Cant read csv file

Tags: java, csv

I write data in csv file but when I read it  while split line it will 
give blank output

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D://codework/bug/myProject/preprocess2.csv"));
BufferedReader resolved = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D://codework/bug/myProject/result.csv"));
File file = new File("D://codework/bug/myProject/categorized1.csv");

FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);

String line = "";
List l = new ArrayList();
List list = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    int i = 01;
    int j = 1;
    String ybest = "Str";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        list.add(line);
        //System.out.println(line);
    }
    for (int l2 = 0; l2 < list.size(); l2++) {
        String str[] = ((String)list.get(l2)).split(",");
        String s = str[1];
        System.out.println(str[1]);
    }
```

Comment: I read file and store in list.And then read list and split

Comment: Please show your csv file and the code where your read that file. Or in other words: create a [mcve].

Comment: Can you please also add your `preprocess2.csv` to the question, or if this file contains secret data, then similar data? And please describe what output you get and what you expect instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading the whole line from your file then you should be using `itr.nextLine()` instead of `itr.next()`.

Corrected Code Snippet:

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    String[] object = ((String) itr.nextLine()).split(",");
    System.out.println(object[0]);
    System.out.println(object[1]);
    System.out.println(object[2]);
}
```

Input:

```
foo bar 1,foo bar 2,foo bar 3
```

Output:

```
foo bar 1
foo bar 2
foo bar 3
```

Comment: Only if you think that `itr` is a `Scanner` and not an `Iterator`.

Comment: @Tom Ah! Sorry, I kind of assumed that it is Scanner. My mistake.

Comment: @Tom and being a Scanner and without modification this is the accepted answer? Code works for OP??

Comment: @VishalKawade Does this code solve your problem? If not, then don't accept it.

Comment: @JordiCastilla Yes, very strange. Maybe OP doesn't know what this tick means?

Comment: dunno, but really weird xD